# conditional assignment of tf.variable in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, tensorflow2.0

For numpy we have

```
threshold = 3
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
a[a>=3] = 199

# a is [1, 2, 199, 199, 199, 199]
```

How to write a similar code in `tensorflow 2`

```
b = tf.Variable(a)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) to conditionally set values:

```
b = tf.Variable(a)
tf.where(b >= 3, 199, b)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([  1,   2, 199, 199, 199, 199])>
```

Comment: Hi@cs95, Thanks for the answer. Will `tf.where(b>=3, 199, b)` be plugin to the computational graph and affect the gradient of `b` in the back propragration? Thanks,

Comment: @jason Couldn't tell you for sure, sorry. Perhaps you could open a follow up question.

Comment: Sure, the problem is in this post now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449945/what-types-of-operations-will-will-not-plugin-the-computational-graph-in-the-ten

Comment: @jason Good luck with the question, I'll see if I can do any digging.