# What types of operations will/will not plugin the computational graph in the Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, gradient, autodiff

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449671/conditional-assignment-of-tf-variable-in-tensorflow-2#65449671), we can change the `tf.variable`

```
threshold = 3
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = tf.Variable(a)
b = tf.where(b >= threshold, 199, b)
```

Will `b=tf.where(b>=3, 199, b)` be plugin to the computational graph and affect the gradient of `b` in the back propragration?

Or more general questions:
What types of operations will/will not plugin the computational graph in the `Tensorflow 2`?